# Mosaic Plot does not fit

Tags: r, plot, mosaic

The labels for the mosaic plot don't fit the screen ( they're partially cut) so id like to move/shift the plot to the right so that the labels fully fit -- tried using ''par'' function but to no avail -- any ideas?

```
structure(list(Road_Type = structure(c(4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L
), .Label = c("Roundabout", "One way Street", "Dual Carriageway", 
"Single carriageway", "Slip Road"), class = "factor"), Accident_Severity_combined = structure(c(2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("Serious", "Slight"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("Road_Type", 
"Accident_Severity_combined"), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
> 


mos <- mosaic(~Road_Type + Accident_Severity_combined, data = uk1,              shade = TRUE, legend = TRUE,
labeling_args = list(set_varnames =     c(Accident_Severity_combined="Gender", Road_Type="survival"),
highlighting_fill = c("darlblue","red")
labeling=labeling_border(
rot_labels = c(90, 0, 90, 0), 
just_labels=c("left","left","right","right"),
tl_varnames = FALSE,
gp_labels = gpar(fontsize = 9)))
```

Comment: Could you add your data (or dummy data, or change the example to use a built in data set)? It will be easier for others to help you if they can reproduce your plot

Comment: sure -- above edited